# Prove $(L^*)^*=L^*$

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJqT4.png

How would I do this? I have tried to think of a solution but nothing comes to my mind.

Comment: Show your own efforts, and also define all your symbols.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: $L$, $L^*$ and $(L^*)^*$ are languages. That means they are *sets* of words. What straightforward way do you know to prove equality between sets ?

Comment: I just started with languages and haven't really understood so much. Guess I can't use any exponent laws?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $L^*\subseteq (L^*)^*$. (Each symbol is a word of length 1).

Conversely take any word $w\in (L^*)^*$. From its definition, it's a concatenation $w=u_1\cdots u_n$ , where each $u_i\in L^*$. 
From the definition of $L^*$ we have $u_i=v_{(i,1)}\cdots v_{(i,k_i)}$ where all $v_{(i,j)}\in L$. 
So we can write
$$w=(v_{(1,1)}\cdots v_{(1,k_1)})\cdots (v_{(n,1)}\cdots v_{(n, k_n)})$$
and $w\in L^*$ as it's a concatenation of symbols in $L$.